# How do I make a view page URL be in the destination parameter?

Tags: views

I have a Views Page and some of the rows contain links.

I want to send the User back to the Views page after clicking the link via the Destination parameter but do not want to hardcode the Views' URL into the link.

Is it possible to use a token in a Views row for the current view URL?

Comment: I have the same question. In the view (name view01) I have a link to edit an entry, and in this link it is added: ?destination=/view01. I would like to have all the view parameters in the destination